# Разделить слова на общенародные, социально ограниченные, диалектно ограниченные

Tags: лексика

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли разделены слова:

***Общенародные***
Ботва
Бусы
Буча  
Винт  
Ведро
Горбуша
Журавель
Мост
Шаньга

***Социально ограниченные***
Банник
Беглый огонь
Борт
Буй
Бушлат
Валек
Вага
Выщелачивание
Делянка
Драить
Завеска
Займище
Клетчатка
Кожух
Компост
Перегной
Прясло
Помпа
Посконь
Сусло
Фуганок
Шабер

***Диалектно ограниченные***
Бирюк
Бровка
Буруны 
Векша 
Вехотка
Веред
Волна (шерсть)
Горенка
Жалмерка
Загнетка
Катанцы
Козуля
Майдан
Пимы
Рогач
Сени
Утлая
Чапельник
Шесток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буча - просторечие, социально огранич.

Журавель - диалект, (норма журавль).

Шаньга - диалект.

Перегной - общенародное.

Шабер - (сосед) диалект.

Волна (шерсть) - разве не термин? Если да, то это социально огранич.